# Standalone executable from a C++ code

Tags: c++, makefile, executable

I have a `C++` code with multiple classes (several `.cpp` and `.h` files) and a Makefile that I initially created on Linux. Now, I need to provide this code to someone, while I preferably do not want to give the source code. I was wondering if there's a possibility to generate a standalone executable from the code that can be used by a different person on their machine, no matter their platform or OS.

Comment: If you build a statically linked executable, other Linux variants should be able to run it without to much trouble. macOS and Windows not so much.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Would something like `$ g++ -o main main.o -static` do the job knowing that apart from `main.cpp`, I have other `.cpp` files too?

Comment: You need to build with all files. Directly from source or from object files.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must make it in C++ and have it execute in some unknown OS, you could compile it inside a VM and package it along with the VM. Otherwise I would recommend using Java, as it was designed to do exactly what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

You can [cross compile for multiple platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler). This results in one executable for each platform. Another way to do it is to [run a Virtual machine inside your binary](https://youtu.be/t4etEwG2_LY).